# Why can't there be complex numbers in the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Is this rule/convention something mathematicians simply agreed upon, like always rationalizing the denominator when it contains a radical expression, or is there a logical/mathematical reason for this?

My current understanding of math is only up to pre-calculus, so any explanation beyond that will most likely go over my head.

Comment: It's just convention. And a convention that isn't really followed after high school math, in my experience.

Comment: Who says there cannot be complex numbers in a denominator?

Comment: I can't say I speak for all mathematicians, but a division by a real number is easy to visualize. A division by a nontrivial complex number is not.

Comment: Dividing a complicated expression by an integer is probably considered easier to grasp than dividing *by* a complicated expression, whatever complicated means in the respective context. In the end, it is a *convention* similar to the one to give fractions in lowest terms, e.g., $\frac12$ instead of $\frac 36$. Then again, we say $25\%$, which is literally $\frac{25}{100}$  instead of $\frac14$ ...

Comment: See for example $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ in Wikipedia's statement of [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). Or Euler's formula $$ \sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} $$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Whily you can get ridof the $i$ in the denominator, I wonder how you would *rationalize* the denominator ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: The question said: "_like_ always rationalizing the denominator _when it contains a radical expression_". It's a simile, not a recipe for getting rid of imaginary terms (should one want that).

Comment: Complex numbers can be thought of as 2 dimensional numbers where addition can be thought of as vector addition and multiplication as combined rotation and stretching. This idea is lost if you don't put results into the a + bi format i.e rationalise the denominator to get the idea of the complex number as a vector (a, b). However, as pointed as by Henning many important theorems keep a complex denominator where the idea on a complex number in the denominator near zero is more important. Ideas drive the choice.

Comment: @HenningMakholm My Algebra textbook, on the section dividing complex numbers, gave instructions to eliminate the complex number in the denominator by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator, and even likened this to the process of rationalizing the denominator. When I googled my question, the same instructions were given in multiple articles. This lead me to believe that complex numbers were not allowed in the denominator.

Comment: @Slecker: That's a procedure for evaluating the result of the division into $a+bi$ form. Whether you _want_ to do that is something you decide.

Comment: And just because your textbook tells you how to divide by complex numbers doesn't mean that dividing by complex numbers is _not allowed_ ... (if it was forbidden, the textbook probably would have told you how to do it).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Unfortunately, the textbook, doesn't provide that caveat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *can* be complex non-real numbers in the denominator. It just happens that if you have an expression of the type$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di},$$with $d\neq0$, if you convert it to$$\frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{(c+di)(c-di)}=\frac{ac+bd+i(bc-ad)}{c^2+d^2},$$you get, in general, a more readable expression.

But you are not *required* to do this. Complex Analysis has lots of formulas that begin with $\frac1{2\pi i}$ and, as far as I know, nobody ever suggested that one should use $-\frac i{2\pi}$ instead.

Comment: Importantly, this computation shows that the quotient equals $\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}+\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}i$, so the complex numbers are closed under division (except by $0$)!

Comment: It's a small point but worth mentioning, for those that don't know that, given $c+di$, $c-di$ is referred to as the conjugate. So that the product of any complex number with its conjugate is real. The conjugate is indicated with a bar so if $z=c+di$ then $\overline{z}=c-di$. So $z.\overline{z}$ is always real.